# Does travis should install composer dev dependencies?

Tags: composer-php, travis-ci

I am wondering what are the travis composer arg recommendations ?
I can not find bests practices about it.

I set up the following: `composer install --ansi --prefer-dist --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader --no-suggest --no-progress` but should I add the `--no-dev` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it really depends on whether you need them. Dev dependencies should be used for development purposes, running tests and so on. If you don't use them, there's no reason to keep them around.

Comment: So has my travis build runs my tests suite, I have to install dev dependencies. Thanks.